# Unable to apply quicksort on array via the usage of pointer arithmatic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

So I have been working on this project of mine but I seem to hit a issue. Technically there are 2 issue, one it will not sort and two I can not debug as i keep hitting segfaults. I must read in a file of data (strings,ints, or doubles). With that, put it in an array and then apply quick sort on it. The data type is given to us thus we can apply the correct type of compare to the data.  Though the rest is a bit hazy. Here is the code I have thus far:

```c
/**
 * Swaps the values in two pointers.
 *
 * Casts the void pointers to character types and works with them as char
 * pointers for the remainder of the function.
 * Swaps one byte at a time, until all 'size' bytes have been swapped.
 * For example, if ints are passed in, size will be 4. Therefore, this function
 * swaps 4 bytes in a and b character pointers.
 */

static void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
  unsigned char * p = a, * q = b, tmp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i  < size; ++i)
    {
        tmp = p[i];
        p[i] = q[i];
        q[i] = tmp;
    }
}

/*
 * Partitions array around a pivot, utilizing the swap function.
 * Each time the function runs, the pivot is placed into the correct index of
 * the array in sorted order. All elements less than the pivot should
 * be to its left, and all elements greater than or equal to the pivot should be
 * to its right.
 * The function pointer is dereferenced when it is used.
 * Indexing into void *array does not work. All work must be performed with
 * pointer arithmetic.
 */
static int lomuto(void *array, int left, int right, size_t elem_sz,
                  int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
    char *ptr = array;
    int s = left;
    for (int i = left+1; i <= right; ++i){
      if( ((comp)( ptr+(i*elem_sz) , ptr+(left*elem_sz)  ))< 0 ){
        s++;
        swap( ptr+(s*elem_sz), ptr+(i*elem_sz), elem_sz);
      }
    }
    swap( ptr+(left*elem_sz), ptr+(s*elem_sz), elem_sz);
    return s;
}

/**
 * Sorts with lomuto partitioning, with recursive calls on each side of the
 * pivot.
 * This is the function that does the work, since it takes in both left and
 * right index values.
 */
static void quicksort_helper(void *array, int left, int right, size_t elem_sz,
                             int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
   if (left < right){
        int pi = lomuto(array, left, right,elem_sz,comp); 

        quicksort_helper(array, left, pi-1,elem_sz,comp);  
        quicksort_helper(array, pi + 1, right,elem_sz,comp); 
    }
}


 /**
  * Quicksort function exposed to the user.
  * Calls quicksort_helper with left = 0 and right = len - 1.
  */
void quicksort(void *array, size_t len, size_t elem_sz,
               int (*comp) (const void*, const void*)) {
  quicksort_helper(array,0,len-1,elem_sz,comp);
}
```

I have the input array read in and I print it out to verify that everything is put in the array as it should, it does. Then we go into the `quicksort` method, via the following `quicksort(list, i, sizeof(int),int_cmp);` (if your curious `int_cmp` and other `comp` are just compare methods passed in).Everything is fine until then, things get out of had during `quicksort_helper` and I assume `lomuto`. I try to print the `void *array` in the beginning of the array to see if anything blatantly wrong shows up. I did this via:

```
char **int_array= (char **)array;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
     printf("A[%d] = %s\n",i,int_array[i]);
  }
```

Though that creates segfaults (`printf(...)`). I want to say that my `lomuto` is good but I could be wrong.
Here lastly are 2 example read in file:
int:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

String:

```
uday
food
banana
apple
oranges
```

Comment: Missing `comp`. Post a [mcve].

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here that is not shown is the compare function for string, casting issue. What the correct version should be is `char *str1 = *((char**)a);`. As well as the parition that was used was a more complicated then it needed to be thus I switched to a different one found on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hoares-vs-lomuto-partition-scheme-quicksort/).I had than also removed the `unsigned` from the swap as it was not needed in my eyes, and last but not least I did not parse the data in correctly for the sorting. Meaning I had a list of numbers in string form when they should of been an int array passed in.